# Density of CLT functions for ergodic dynamical systems

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, central-limit-theorem

> Assume that $ ( X , \mathcal A , \mu ) $ is a probability space, $ T : X \to X $ is an ergodic transformation, and $ f \in L ^ 2 ( \mu ) $ is such that $ \int f \ \mathrm d \mu = 0 $ and $ \frac { S _ m ( f ) } { \| S _ m ( f ) \| } $ converges in distribution to $ \mathcal N ( 0 , 1 ) $. Here, $ \mathcal N ( 0 , 1 ) $ is the standard normal distribution, $ \| . \| $ is the $ L ^ 2 ( \mu ) $ norm and $ S _ m ( f ) = \sum _ { i = 0 } ^ { m - 1 } f \circ T ^ m $. Prove that for any $ \phi \in L ^ 2 ( \mu ) $, $ \frac { S _ m ( f + \phi \circ T - \phi ) } { \| S _ m ( f + \phi \circ T - \phi ) \| } $ also converges in distribution to $ \mathcal N ( 0 , 1 ) $.

This problem comes from studying the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) for dynamical systems. In "[On the Central Limit Theorem for Dynamical Systems](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2000864)" by Burton and Denker, the authors claim without proof that if the function $ f \in L ^ 2 ( \mu ) $ satisfies CLT, then for any functions of the form $ \phi \circ T - \phi $ for some ergodic $ T $, $ f + \phi \circ T - \phi $ also satisfies CLT. Consequently, the functions satisfying CLT are dense in the subspace of the functions in $ L ^ 2 ( \mu ) $ with zero integral, because functions of the form $ \phi \circ T - \phi $ are dense in that subspace.

I can observe that $ S _ m ( f + \phi \circ T - \phi ) = S _ m ( f ) + \phi \circ T ^ m - \phi $. As $ T $ is ergodic, the fraction $ \frac { S _ m ( f ) + \phi \circ T ^ m - \phi } m $ converges almost sure to $ 0 $, by Birkhoff ergodic theorem. But I can't replace the $ m $ in the denominator by $ \| S _ m ( f ) + \phi \circ T ^ m - \phi \| $.

I'm familiar with the proof of CLT in case of an i.i.d.; but in this case $ ( f \circ T ^ m ) _ m $ is not an i.i.d. sequence. I can't figure out how to approach this problem.

---

*Burton, Robert; Denker, Manfred*, [**On the central limit theorem for dynamical systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2000864), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 302, 715-726 (1987). [ZBL0628.60030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0628.60030).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see the result if we assume that $\lVert S_m(f) \rVert\to\infty$. In this case,
$$
 \lVert S_m(f) \rVert-2\lVert \phi \rVert\leqslant \| S _ m ( f ) + \phi \circ T ^ m - \phi \|\leq \lVert S_m(f) \rVert+2\lVert \phi \rVert
$$
hence
$$\tag{1}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{ \| S _ m ( f ) + \phi \circ T ^ m - \phi \|}{\lVert S_m(f) \rVert}=1
$$
and
$$
\tag{2}
\left(\phi\circ T^m-\phi\right)/\lVert S_m(f) \rVert\to 0\mbox{ in probability}
$$
hence the central limit theorem for $f+\phi\circ T-\phi$ follows from (1), (2) and standard properties of convergence in distribution of random variables.

However, it might be an other story if we do not assume that $\lVert S_m(f) \rVert\to\infty$. Indeed, let $\Omega$ be a product space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Z}$, $T$ the shift and $\mu$ the product measure of $\mu_i$, the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R$. Let $f\colon (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z}\mapsto x_0-x_1$, then $S_m(f)/\lVert S_n(f)\rVert$ is standard normal. However, adding a co-boundary of the form $\phi\circ T-\phi$ where $\phi\colon (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z}\mapsto x_0x_1-x_1x_2$ can spoil the central limit theorem.

Nevertheless, it is not what is claimed in the paper: they just say that when, the dynamical system is ergodic, the co-boundaries are dense in the subspace of mean-zero functions, giving an other argument for the proof of the fact that the set of the functions which satisfy the central limit theorem is dense in $\mathbb L^2$.

In other words, if $CLT$ is the set of square integrable functions such satisfying the central limit theorem in the paper, pick a centered $f_0$ in the set $CLT$ such that $\lVert S_n(f_0)\rVert\to\infty$ (the existence is given by Theorem 1. Then by the argument given at the beginning of the answer, $f_0+\phi\circ T-\phi$ belongs to $CLT$ for each square integrable function $\phi$ hence the closure of $CLT$ in $\mathbb L^2$ contains the closure of the set of functions of the form $f_0+\phi\circ T-\phi$, which is $\mathbb L^2$.